Srtool rust nightly not installed
I am trying to build my runtime using the following command
srtool build --root --package my-runtime --runtime-dir node/runtime --build-opts="--features=fast-runtime"

I am getting the following error
Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/build/node/runtime/target/srtool/release/build/my-runtime-14915b32115d2b35/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stderr
  Rust nightly not installed, please install it!

But I have nightly installed.
Following is my active toolchain.
nightly-2022-10-09-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (overridden by '/home/rr/rrr/my-node-rrr/rust-toolchain')
rustc 1.66.0-nightly (8796e7a9c 2022-10-08)


Could you also provide the repo that I can reproduce this locally?
